# Why does gang-nam and viet-nam both contain nam meaning south when one is in Korean the other Vietnamese?

Tags: historical-linguistics, semantics, korean, vietnamese

Does anyone know why there is a character that is common to both the Koreans and the Vietnamese?

Are there any other examples of these kind of similarity?

Comment: Half Korean-Vietnamese is called "KorViet".

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Nán (南) is "south" in Chinese.

Addendum: the Middle Chinese form assumed by Sagert & Baxter is *nom*. The reconstructions from their book are available [here](http://ocbaxtersagart.lsait.lsa.umich.edu/BaxterSagartOCbyMandarinMC2014-09-20.pdf).

Comment: *nan2* is 'south' in Mandarin, but it doesn't explain the /n/ final. The best explanation is that Vietnamese and Korean both borrowed 南 from Middle Chinese, which had a /m/ final.

Comment: Thanks: I assumed it was originally *m but didn't know the Middle Chinese form

Comment: This was basically the same answer I was going to post but it might be more helpful to future users if you edit your answer to make it clear that both Vietnamese and Korean borrowed the word for "south" from some Chinese dialect, and that we know this becuase both languages use/used Chinese characters in some capacity. Maybe provide the Chinese character versions of each name.

Comment: Does anyone know when Vietnamese and Korean borrowed most of their Korean vocabulary? How about from which Chinese Dialect[s]? Given that 南 in Korean, Vietnamese, and Cantonese all end in an /m/, I'm inclined to beleive that Mandarin too used to have the /m/ coda but it morphed into the /n/. Is this accurate? When did this happen?

Comment: Most of the Chinese vocabulary in Vietnamese was borrowed from Middle Chinese during the Tang period, but a smaller number of words were borrowed already from Old Chinese in the early Han period.

Comment: @acattle. Most of the Chinese vocabulary in Vietnamese (and, I believe, in Japanese and Korean) is not borrowed from "some Chinese dialect" but from the bureaucratic koine of the Tang empire, as reflected in the rhyme dictionaries. The borrowing did not take place at a spoken level but at the level of official scholarly writing.

Comment: @fdb That may be the case in Japanese (where 1 kanji character can be multiple syllables long) but it is not the case in Korean (the only of the 3 I have any real experience in). Each Korean Hanja character (their version of Kanji) has a single syllable pronunciation, the majority of which can be traced back to their Chinese pronunciation. I'm just not sure from which dialect nor when the pronunciations were borrowed. The trivial example is Korean's two number systems: the Sino-Korean system is used for quantities while the native Korean system is used for counting.

Comment: it's naam4 in Cantonese, nàm in Hakka and lâm in Min Nan https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/%E5%8D%97

Comment: @acattle in Vietnamese Sino-Vietnamese numbers are used for ordinals while native Vietnamese numbers are used when counting